# Keep playing audio when changing page react/redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm having a big problem here..
I have a component whit tag `<audio>` on my `/home`, when I clicked the music begins and share the data (title, controls, music) to other player component calls `MainPlayer`. This component its cross to all the views, and the component whit the audio tag only exist in the homepage.. the problem is that if i change the view the music stops..
I 'm using redux to share that data to the other component.
help please! thanks!

example:

app.js
.....

```
render() {

    return (
      <React.Fragment>
          <BrowserRouter>
             <Switch>
                <Route
                  path="/"
                  exact
                  render={props => (
                    <Home
                      {...props}
                      content={this.state.content} --> conten is an ajax response
                    />
                  )}
                />
                <Route
                  path="/services"
                  exact
                  render={props => (
                    <Programs />
                  )}
                />
              )
            }
```

Homejs

```
...
render(){
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
               <ContentGroups content={this.props.content} /> 
            </ React.Fragment> 
        )
    }
```

Contentgroups.js

```
...
render {
   return(
     <ContentAudioList /> // HERE I HAVE THE <AUDIO>
)}
```

Comment: Can you not just move the audio tag outside of the homepage so that it's shared across all views?

Comment: @dbramwell exactly what I cam here to write :-)

Comment: You shouldn't get component mounting/unmounting on each page render if it placed at the same hierarchy in each page. Also, you can use @dbramwell suggestion and move the player audio tag to the top level and just control it through redux.

Comment: Maybe you can put the `audio` tag in the main page and handle subpages with a react router (building a single page application the `audio` tag is "always loaded in the browser" and the music will not stop). The "main page" can be a component (the root component), so you can still share data with redux.

Comment: Also, please add a minimal working example. Try and include only the relevant code if you can. it will help other people on the site help you much quicker

Comment: Thanks , already put an example. The audio tag only must show on the `home`, and the tag audio has an id to come from ajax response..